# Should with()-statements apply to nested functions?

Tags: javascript

Take the following code:

```
var a = new Object();
a.meep = 5;

function foo() {
  with (a) {
    function bar() {
      return meep;
    }
    return bar();
  }
}
```

Code like this failed for me in Chrome and worked in Firefox. Which is right?

Comment: In any case: There are rarely situations where you need `with`. You should avoid using it and [be aware of its problems](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with#Description). It is not even allowed anymore in JS' `strict` mode.

Comment: Typing "gl." hundreds of times is not fun.

Comment: If you have to type it hundreds of times in *one* block, then you should rethink the structure of your application.

Comment: No, there's multiple blocks. And multiple with()s. Typing with half a dozen times easily beats typing gl. a hundred times.

Answer (score 1):

The right thing is too never use `with`. Ever. In any language.

The amount of bugs and wasted development time `with` has caused over the years.... It should be on the blacklist right below `goto`.

If you really don't want to type, use code completion or assign a long expression to a short variable. That said, I'd think this aughta work. It would fit right into the other magic scope trics of Javascript. :)

Answer (score 0):

As general advice: don't use with.

However, to get your code working in Chrome change:

```
var a;
```

to:

```
var a=new Object();
```

and:

```
function bar() {
```

to:

```
var bar = function() {
```

To give complete code like this:

```
var a=new Object();
a.meep = 5;

function foo() {
  with (a) {
    var bar = function() {
      return meep;
    }
    return bar();
  }
}
```

Comment: I already fixed the code. I'm wondering which behavior is "correct".